# Apple - How can we use Touch ID in iOS apps incase of password change

Tags: ios, swift, security, touch-id

I want to use it in my Login screen. In detail, instead of asking user to enter Login Id and Password, I want user to go for Touch Id and if he/she is a device owner, then allow them to go inside app (Post Login screen).

My question is, if the user changes the password using a web application, then in this case touchId should fail. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/q/24158062/3522537

Answer (score 1):

You can use Touch ID to protect a password that is stored in the keychain.  Once the keychain item is unlocked then present the username/password to your web site for verification.  If verification fails then prompt the user to enter the password.  Once the new password has been successfully verified then update the keychain item.

Download the iTunesConnect app for an example of this behaviour.

Sample code on using TouchID with Keychain is here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html